# TinyMCE Button to Insert Multiple Lines of Text?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there a way to get my custom TinyMCE button to insert multiple lines of text? Ultimately I am making a "Premade Themes" button where a user will select a theme and it will insert about 6-8 different shortcodes with one click and they can edit the shortcodes accordingly..

A problem I'm having is that all of these shortcodes get put in one line. Here's the code I use that actually pastes the shortcodes:

`tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceInsertClipboardContent', false, {content : 'the shortcodes go here'});`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be as easy as adding `<br />` between shortcodes or every time you want to add a new line and also if you are inserting content you should use `mceInsertContent` instead of `mceInsertClipboardContent` unless you are actually getting the content from the clipbard, so:

```
tinyMCEPopup.editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p>[shotcode1]<br/>[shotcode2]<br/>[shotcode3]</p>'));
```